# How to call a jquery event trigger while using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in dealing with my problem. My problem is I am creating a static navigation. That uses trigger event. Because I am displaying a simple collapsible div. 
What I did is I include all my id name in an array and I loop it to create an event. But when I click a link i doesn't call my jquery event. Is there a way how can I prevent hard coded of navigation?

Here's my sample code:

```
var toggleState = true;
var header_name = ["ParentA", "ParentB", "ParentC", "ParentD"];
var child_name = ["ChildA", "ChildB", "ChildC", "ChildD"];

for (var x = 0; x < header_name.length; x++) {
    $("#" + header_name[x]).click(function (e) {
        if (toggleState) {
            $("#" + child_name[x]).show("slide");
        } else {
            $("#" + child_name[x]).hide("slide");
        }
        toggleState = !toggleState;
    });
}
<div id="ParentA">Click A</div>
<div id="ChildA" style="display: none">Child A</div>
<div id="ParentB">Click A</div>
<div id="ChildB" style="display: none">Child B</div>
<div id="ParentC">Click A</div>
<div id="ChildC" style="display: none">Child C</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/cveze/3/

Comment: The spaces will give you trouble Replace the spaces in your IDs with underscores.

Comment: Arrays should be inside [] not ().

Comment: Read http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name id must not have spaces

Comment: ok sorry for my wrong array.. i will edit this

Comment: will you be able to make some minor changes to the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make minor changes to the html it should be as simple as

```
<div id="ParentA" class="click-toggle" data-target="#ChildA">Click A</div>
<div id="ChildA" style="display: none">Child A</div>
<div id="ParentB" class="click-toggle" data-target="#ChildB">Click B</div>
<div id="ChildB" style="display: none">Child B</div>
<div id="ParentC" class="click-toggle" data-target="#ChildC">Click C</div>
<div id="ChildC" style="display: none">Child C</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click-toggle').click(function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H5u7S/)

or even

```
<div id="ParentA" class="click-toggle">Click A</div>
<div id="ChildA" style="display: none">Child A</div>
<div id="ParentB" class="click-toggle">Click B</div>
<div id="ChildB" style="display: none">Child B</div>
<div id="ParentC" class="click-toggle">Click C</div>
<div id="ChildC" style="display: none">Child C</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click-toggle').click(function () {
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5xCG/), if you want to maintain left -> right slide: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RnpF9/1/)

to make your code work... the main problem is the use of shared closure variable `toggleState`... each menu item should have its own state variable... the solution is to create a private closure for each one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var header_name = ["ParentA", "ParentB", "ParentC", "ParentD"];
    var child_name = ["ChildA", "ChildB", "ChildC", "ChildD"];
    $.each(header_name, function (idx, id) {
        var toggleState = true;
        $('#' + id).click(function () {
            if (toggleState) {
                $("#" + child_name[idx]).show("slide");
            } else {
                $("#" + child_name[idx]).hide("slide");
            }
            toggleState = !toggleState;
        })
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rpmKj/)

Comment: @RochelleCanale which one did you opt for

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
var header_name = ("Parent A", "Parent B", "Parent C", "Parent D");
```

to this

```
var header_name = ["Parent A", "Parent B", "Parent C", "Parent D"];
```

likewise with the next variable

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a local copy of x for each iteration of the loop.  The simplest way to do this is to create a helper function like `getClickHandler`:

```
function getClickHandler(x) {
    return function(e){
            if(toggleState){
                $("#" + child_name[x]).show("slide");
            }else{
                $("#" + child_name[x]).hide("slide");
            }
            toggleState = !toggleState;
          };
}

for(var x = 0; x < header_name.length; x++){
    $("#" + header_name[x]).click(getClickHandler(x));
}
```

The key point here is that the function inside `click` runs at a later time (asynchronously).  Because of how variable scope works in Javascript, your code passes the same reference to `x` in to each handler, which is why all of them end up getting the last iteration of the array.  Doing the above creates a copy of `x` at the current iteration, and stores it in a local reference (inside the handler function).

Comment: Hi again, i did that but it doesn't work. I included my fiddle in the question.